# Java Native Code Crash Not Prompting To Debug?

Tags: java, c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012, dll

I'm calling a C++ .dll from Java through JNI and previously when it crashed, I'd get the traditional popup asking me if I wanted to open Visual Studio to debug it.  All of the sudden it just closes.  I even tried running an instance of Visual Studio and attached to the process hoping it would catch whatever exception was being thrown and stop.  It sees the exception(s):

```
First-chance exception at 0x027bfeb8 in java.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.
First-chance exception at 0x027c1794 in java.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.
First-chance exception at 0x0281b3a0 in java.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000000000000c.
```

It just keeps going until it closes?

Did I somehow check a box that told my degugger to stop debugging?  Is there a way to force it to catch these exceptions to I can view the stack trace (the .dll is built with debug symbols).  My labmate's computer prompts him to debug it when we recreate the behavior on his machine, so it seems like something I might have accidentally en/disabled.

I did some digging through the tools->options->debugging in visual studio.  Just in Time debugging is enabled for all 3 types.  Under Debug->Exceptions I checked all the types there hoping it would make it catch something, and it does, but I don't think anything related to the ones that are actually causing the problem.

Any ideas how to re-enable the behavior where I get prompted for debugging when something crashes?

Edit:

I've solved my bug through other methods, I was freeing a pointer of value CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC, because it was uninitialized in an array of pointers that was getting looped through.  This doesn't seem like the kind of error that should crash so hard that the debugger can't handle it.  Would still like to know why I couldn't debug in the first place.

Comment: Maybe the debugger crashes as well on displaying the message?

Comment: That's a reasonable guess; unfortunately I'm not sure if there is anything I can do about that.